# ThreadPoolExecutor - Handling concurrency limit - implemented from external api

Tags: python, threadpoolexecutor

currently I have small script that will call an external api to get some data in parallel. So far the concurrency works well for 10 to 20 requests.But currently the external api implemented concurrency limit to 100.If the concurrency exceeds 100, i will get some server error from the api response. So the goal is to call the external api with concurrency but not hitting the limit. By design, we cant control how many params the user can submit from frontend side.

The idea is the user will submit dynamic numbers of params from frontend.

My question, is what is the efficient way to handle concurrency to dynamically handle exceeding params limit?

```
 keywords = ['keyword1',........] // lets say 200 keywords from user form submit, exceeding the 100 limit

 with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
       executor.map(getdata, keywords)
  
 // pesudo code
 def getdata(keyword):
     payload = {"keyword": keyword}
     res = requests.get("http://externalapi.com", params=payload)
     //process the response like save to database
```

Now if the keywords exceeds 100(150), Is it possible to run it by chunk?,so first, it will run with the first 100, then run again with remaining 50.Any ideas how to implement it?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding optional chunksize

```
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(getdata, keywords, chunksize=90)
```

Now the response improve more than twice the previous implementation